# Spring Security Configuration Returning 401 Unauthorized for All Request

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, security, spring-security

I set-up my Springboot project with Spring Security and implemented the Spring Configuration with In-memory authentication. Just a simple authenticated. However, no matter what I do it's not working at all and is giving me 401 Unauthorized for any request in both Spring Security Login form and Postman.

I tried different solution but nothing seems to be working. I get 401 every single time.
I tried adding the componentScan, the filter order, the auto config exclusion, simple password, encrypted password. Nothing works.

Application:

```
@EnableEurekaClient
@SpringBootApplication
@ComponentScan(basePackages = "sdp.training.gatewayservice.security")
public class GatewayServiceApplication {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(GatewayServiceApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

Security Configuration

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true, securedEnabled = true)
public class SecurityConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    public void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        // First encrypt the password string
        String encodedPassword = passwordEncoder().encode("javainuse");

        // Set the password
        UserDetails user = User.builder()
                .username("javainuse")
                .password(encodedPassword)
                .roles("USER")
                .build();

        // Use in-memory authentication with BCryptEncoder
        auth.inMemoryAuthentication()// .passwordEncoder(NoOpPasswordEncoder.getInstance())
                .withUser(user)
                .passwordEncoder(passwordEncoder());
    }

    @Override
    public void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.csrf().disable();
        http.authorizeRequests()
        .antMatchers("/testBruh").permitAll()
        .anyRequest().authenticated()
        .and().formLogin().permitAll()
        .and().httpBasic();
    }

    @Bean
    public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }

}
```

Simple Controller

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping(value = "/testBruh")
public class TestController {

    @GetMapping
    public ResponseEntity<Object> getAccounts() {
        return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.OK).body("YO");
    }
}
```

Application.properties

```
spring.application.name: gateway-service
server.port: 8090

# spring.autoconfigure.exclude=org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.security.SecurityAutoConfiguration

# spring.security.user.name=admin
# spring.security.user.password=123456
# spring.security.user.roles=manager
spring.security.filter.order=10

spring.main.allow-bean-definition-overriding=true

spring.cloud.gateway.routes[0].id=accountService
spring.cloud.gateway.routes[0].uri=lb://account-service
spring.cloud.gateway.routes[0].predicates[0].name=Path
spring.cloud.gateway.routes[0].predicates[0].args.pattern=/account-service/**
spring.cloud.gateway.routes[0].filters[0]=StripPrefix=1
spring.cloud.gateway.routes[1].id=blogService
spring.cloud.gateway.routes[1].uri=lb://blog-service
spring.cloud.gateway.routes[1].predicates[0].name=Path
spring.cloud.gateway.routes[1].predicates[0].args.pattern=/blog-service/**
spring.cloud.gateway.routes[1].filters[0]=StripPrefix=1
```

Comment: and where are your full debug logs?